# kafka-connect org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character $

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using jdbc source connector and getting below error when I want to connect with a table that has "$" in the name.

```
org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character <<tablename>>$
```

I tried escaping this with utf-8 like tablename\u0024, still the same error.

How to deal with these special chars?

Comment: You could use the JSONConverter instead. The error comes from the AvroConverter, which doesn't have much configuration options for something like this

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the schema validation isn't happy with the schema name that has been created from your table name.  You can override this with [SetSchemaMetadata](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/setschemametadata.html), there is an example in the docs like this:

```
"transforms": "SetSchemaMetadata",
"transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value",
"transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.schema.name": "avro"
```

This will set the schema name for the value message field.